# NodeMCU traceback on reboot

Tags: lua, traceback, nodemcu

I have an embedded application running NodeMCU that is not connected to a console as the UART has been repurposed to obtain serial data from an attached device.

During testing the application ran for about 15 hours then rebooted 5 times in a row before "settling" and continuing to run correctly.

Is it possible to log to a file a traceback of what caused the reboots? I am assuming some kind of PANIC error caused the reboot. I don't think it is a memory issue as the application reports the heap size (via http to a local server) every 30 seconds. Here is a log extract:

```
Wed May 18 00:46:37 2016 -> '{"s":"1782","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12408
Wed May 18 00:47:08 2016 -> '{"s":"1783","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12408
Wed May 18 00:47:39 2016 -> '{"s":"1784","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12408
Wed May 18 00:48:19 2016 -> '{"s":"1785","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=11432
Wed May 18 00:50:06 2016 -> '{"s":"0","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=14560
Wed May 18 00:51:25 2016 -> '{"s":"0","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=14584
Wed May 18 00:52:45 2016 -> '{"s":"0","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=14560
Wed May 18 00:54:04 2016 -> '{"s":"0","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=14584
Wed May 18 00:55:24 2016 -> '{"s":"0","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=14608
Wed May 18 00:55:55 2016 -> '{"s":"1","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12608
Wed May 18 00:56:26 2016 -> '{"s":"2","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12600
Wed May 18 00:56:56 2016 -> '{"s":"3","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12624
Wed May 18 00:57:27 2016 -> '{"s":"4","i":"1afe34d26348", "d":"heap=12600
```

I the above log "s" is a sequential counter that is reset to 0 when the device reboots, and "d" is the heap size (you can ignore the "i" entry, it is just the MAC address of the device that is sending the data).

xpcall won't work in the case of a PANIC device reset.

I tried logging [node.bootreason()](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodebootreason) to a file on reboot, but it doesn't contain a traceback to where the error occurred.

Is there some method for troubleshooting nodemcu applications that aren't connected to a console?

Comment: `node.bootreason()` can at least tell you if it was hardware, software, watchdog, exception so its information is valuable to have. https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/795 contains lots of useful hints as for how to tackle this (enable debug log, map file). However, you only get a map file if you build the firmware yourself: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/build/. Can you keep it connected to a console for a few dozen hours?

Comment: I will log node.bootreason to a file on startup, and will disconnect my serial device so that i can connect to the console and run for some hours.  I had a look at issue 795 and there are some good ideas, but my understanding of nodemcu is going to have to greatly increase before I can implement them!